# How do have 1 window instead of multiple windowsss, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to have only 1 window, instead of many. I currently use Visual Studio Code, is there a way to integrate the commands into the terminal of VSC? It's very annoying to have so many processes open with nodejs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to this link: [How to hide node cmd windows created by "pm2 start"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134794/how-to-hide-node-cmd-windows-created-by-pm2-start/51071113#51071113)

there is an answer that explains how, but for the sake of it, you just need to add in the settings:

```
//Terminal Configurations

//PowerShell Windows
//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",

//GIT Bash Configuration
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

Please +1 if it helps. Thanks :)